# How can I copy text from Books.app in 2023?

Tags: macos, books

On macOS Monterey in Books.app, how can I copy some text from a book directly?

If I select

> Letter of Marque spike loot. Haul wind man-of-war holystone ahoy bounty flogging Jack Tar heave to execution dock tackle.

then pressing cmd-c actually puts

> “Letter of Marque spike loot. Haul wind man-of-war holystone ahoy bounty flogging Jack Tar heave to execution dock tackle.”
>
> Excerpt From
> The Book I Am Reading
> Its Author
> This material may be protected by copyright.

into my clipboard instead.

How can I copy the text itself?

Comment: To be clear, you want to copy a selection of text without the appended reference automatically included?

Comment: @Allan yes! precisely (nor the quotation marks)

Comment: I don’t use Books so it took me some time to get this set up to test.  At present, I haven’t found a way to disable it.  I understand what Apple is doing, but this can be annoying